# Why is my GPA Double value not working correctly in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, ios9

why isn't this code working when I addA for the first time it works but then it goes to 2.66 and keeps going down from there when it should stay at 4.0.

```
import UIKit

//Quantity of          A    A-   B+   B    B-   C+   C    C-   D+   D    D-   F
var gradesQuantity = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
var gradesAdded = 0.0
var gpa = 0.0

func addGrades(grades: [Double]) -> Double {
    for grade in grades {
        gradesAdded += grade
        if gradesQuantity[0] <= 0 {
            gradesQuantity[0] = 0
        }
    }

    return gradesAdded
}

func calcGPA(grades: [Double]) -> Double {
    gpa = (grades[0] * 4.0 + grades[1] * 3.7 + grades[2] * 3.3 + grades[3] * 3.0 + grades[4] * 2.7 + grades[5] * 2.3 + grades[6] * 2.0 + grades[7] * 1.7 + grades[8] * 1.3 + grades[9] * 1.0 + grades[10] * 0.7) / gradesAdded

    return gpa
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var GPALabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var GPANumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var AQuantity: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func AddA() {
        gradesQuantity[0] += 1.0
        addGrades(gradesQuantity)
        let x = calcGPA(gradesQuantity)
        GPANumber.text = String(x)
        AQuantity.text = String(Int(gradesQuantity[0]))
    }

    @IBAction func SubtractA() {
        gradesQuantity[0] -= 1.0
        addGrades(gradesQuantity)
        let x = calcGPA(gradesQuantity)
        GPANumber.text = String(x)
        AQuantity.text = String(Int(gradesQuantity[0]))
    }
}
```

can somebody please help i put this in playground and add code under it that is the same in the buttons and it works but in the project it doesnt work. This leads me to believe the problem is in the addA and subtractA buttons.

Comment: Can you explain some more about what the app is supposed to do and how the gpa is weighted?

Comment: Shouldn't you reset `gradesAdded` to 0 each time you calculate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the root cause of your problem is that you are doing too much work. If you delete the `addGrades` function (which isn't really adding any functionality as far as I can tell) and replace your `AddA` and `SubtractA` functions with the following, then it will work as intended:

```
@IBAction func AddA() {
    gradesQuantity[0] += 1.0
    gradesAdded += 1.0
    GPANumber.text = String(calcGPA(gradesQuantity))
    AQuantity.text = String(Int(gradesQuantity[0]))
}

@IBAction func SubtractA() {
    gradesQuantity[0] -= 1.0
    gradesAdded -= 1.0
    GPANumber.text = String(calcGPA(gradesQuantity))
    AQuantity.text = String(Int(gradesQuantity[0]))
}
```

For further development, I would recommend creating a subclass array that has functions to add and subtract grades and return the GPA. This should make things much more readable and reusable.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing functions with side effects (modifying external variables). Try to avoid that. Also, you may want to have a bit more structure in your program. Associate positional value of `gradesQuantity` to a letter grade is ok, but you can do better with a Dictionary:

```
enum GradeLetter: Double {
    case A = 4.0
    case AMinus = 3.7
    case BPlus = 3.3
    case B = 3
    case BMinus = 2.7
    case CPlus = 2.3
    case C = 2
    case CMinus = 1.7
    case DPlus = 1.3
    case D = 1
    case DMinus = 0.7
    case F = 0
}

func calculateGPA(grades: [GradeLetter: Int]) -> Double {
    let courseCount = grades.reduce(0.0) { aggregate, grade in
        return aggregate + Double(grade.1)
    }
    let totalPoint = grades.reduce(0.0) { aggregate, grade in
        return aggregate + grade.0.rawValue * Double(grade.1)
    }

    return totalPoint / courseCount
}
```

Let's say you have 1 `A`, 2 `A-` and 3 `B`:

```
var grades = [GradeLetter: Int]()
grades[.A] = 1
grades[.AMinus] = 2
grades[.B] = 3

print(calculateGPA(grades))
```